For $x^{\prime}\cdot t+ c\cdot x =f(t)$ if $c<-1$ every local solution can be extended to global solution $x(t) \in (-a,a)$
I have that ODE:

$$x^{\prime}\cdot t+ c\cdot x =f(t)$$

Here $c$ is a constant and $f \in C^{1}(-a,a)$.
The question is:

a) Prove that if $c<-1$ then any local solution $x(t)$ can be extended to global solution $x(t) \in C^{1}(-a,a)$


b) if $c>0$ find all the solutions that can be extended to global solutions $x(t) \in C^{-1}(-a,a)$

My attempt:
I couldn't figure out a), so that's my attmept for it:
I wanted to take some local solution $x(t)$ and see what it satisfies in an interval that it define in it but zero isn't in that interval, in that interval holds:
$$x^{\prime}+\frac{c}{t}\cdot x=\frac{f(t)}{t}$$
and we get can to that: $$\left(e^{\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\frac{c}{s}ds}\cdot x\right)^{\prime} =e^{\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\frac{c}{s}ds}\cdot\frac{f(t)}{t}$$
Here $t_0$ is not initial point, it's the infimum of our interval (if the infimum is zero we can take smaller interval), so $$x=t^{-c}\cdot\left(\int_{t_0}^{t}u^{c}\cdot\frac{f(u)}{u}du+C\right)$$
But in the integral there is no cancellation so I can't say that $x(t)$ is defined in $(-a,a)$
I also tried to explore the solutions for the homogeneous ODE and found that $t^{-c}$ is a solution so I tried to do variation of constant $\tilde{x}(t)=x(t)\cdot t^{-c}$ and get to
$$x^{\prime}(t)\cdot t^{-c}\cdot t+(t^{-c})^{\prime}\cdot x(t)\cdot t+c\cdot x(t)\cdot t^{-c}=f(t)$$
But $$(t^{-c})^{\prime}\cdot x(t)+c\cdot x(t)\cdot t^{-c}=x(t)\cdot\underbrace{\left((t^{-c})^{\prime}\cdot t+c\cdot t^{-c}\right)}_{0}=0$$
Hence: $$x^{\prime}(t)\cdot t^{-c}\cdot t=f(t)$$ but it's problematic as well..
I'll be glad for some help in that question, thank you all in advance!

What do you mean $f\in C^1(-a,a)$?

@xpaul
f is continuously differentiable at the interval $(-a,a)$

You mean $t\in (-a,a)$?
